# Map Chebyshev nodes on an arbitrary shape?

Tags: interpolation, chebyshev-polynomials

Is it possible to map Chebyshev nodes on an arbitrary shape (e.g. in 2D: on a triangle, in 3D: on a cone or pyramid)? The Chebyshev nodes will be used as interpolation points?

Thanks.

Comment: It certainly is possible to consider a Cartesian product of Chebyshev nodes and then find a suitable (conformal?) mapping from the hypercube (square in 2D) to your desired shape (whether this is practical is a different question), but then why not consider the [Padua points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padua_points) or [Fekete/Lebesgue points](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2011.12.006) instead?